# How to use Jetty with Let's Encrypt certificates?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I want to use certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) with a large count of Jetty servers. One of the problems is that the certificates from Let's Encrypt has a [lifetime of 90 days](https://letsencrypt.org/2015/11/09/why-90-days.html).

To handle this the Jetty server or some extra code must renew the certificate frequently.

- Can Jetty handle this self? If yes how can I enable this?
- If I need to implement it self with a [Java client](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) then how can I replace the certificate dynamically via Jetty API without a restart of the Jetty server?

Edit: Some related and partial helpful links:

- [setting ssl keystore at runtime in Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706333/setting-ssl-keystore-at-runtime-in-jetty)
- [Changing Jetty SSL server certificate on-the-fly](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07260.html)

Comment: Do you have a working sample of this? I have a similar requirement. It would be good to have a working sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 9.3.15 you can use:

```
SslContextFactory.reload(Consumer<SslContextFactory>)
```

For details see at: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/918

Comment: @NausherwanAslam Do you means a sample for the reload or for Let's Encrypt?

Comment: https://danielflower.github.io/2017/04/08/Lets-Encrypt-Certs-with-embedded-Jetty.html seems to give an example if it helps.