# Allow https for more than one port by certbot

Tags: java, https, jetty, google-compute-engine

I have Google compute engine (GCE) with web that listens to port 80 and 443 by node.

Also I have Jetty server (Java) that listens to port 8080.

I wanted to support HTTPS, so I added certbot standalone to manage it([certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianbuster-other)).

Now I have HTTPS that works fine for the web (port 80 and 443).

The problem is that all the requests I'm sending to the port 8080 from the web fail with error:
`net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.`

Very important that everything has been working fine before I added the HTTPS support.

Please help to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` due to wrong Jetty server configuration - it uses plain HTTP instead of SSL encrypted HTTPS protocol.

You need to configure you Jetty server to use the certificate that you already have (and use). It's similar process that configuring web server. It has to "know" where the certificate files are.

Have a look at this site - it describes in detail how to do this.

I found a tutorial that may help you [Configuring Jetty for HTTPS with Let's Encrypt](https://www.sorcerers-tower.net/articles/configuring-jetty-for-https-with-letsencrypt) and also it was discussed [here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427066/how-to-use-jetty-with-lets-encrypt-certificates) (which I believe will be the closest to your use case).